# Running Selenium with Python3 on Remote Server - Error NotADirectory, Gecko Not on PATH

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.4, geckodriver

I am having this problem getting selenium to run with python3. The first is when I do:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I get the error geckodriver is not PATH. I downloaded geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases then create a directory called gecko and do

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/gecko
```

I repeat the process of declaring the webdriver and then I got this error:

File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in **init**
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 64, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in **init**
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory

I already have xvfb installed for running the browser headless and issue the command xvfb-run python3 to start the python interactive shell. I am baffled as to why I continue to get this error message.

How do I solve it? Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks.